# Error regarding switch expression (must be a bool, char, string etc.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, switch-statement

I am adding a voice control feature to my program. I have an error with the code, which I cannot seem to get rid of. The voice control will allow the user to control aspects of the program without using a mouse or keyboard.

Currently, my code consists of:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using FontCombo;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

if (voctrl.Checked == true)
        {
            vcstat.Text = "Voice Control Enabled";
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
            recognizer.SpeechDetected += recognizer_SpeechDetected;
            recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
            GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
            grammar.Append(new Choices("Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "Select All", "Print", "Deselect All", "Delete", "Save", "Save As", "Open", "New", "Close"));
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammar));
        }
        else
        {
            vcstat.Text = "Voice Control Disabled";
        }

private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (voctrl.Checked == true)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text.ToUpper) //This is the error according to Visual Studio
            {
                case
                "Cut":
                    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
                    richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedRtf = "";
                    break; // etc.
```

I have tried searching the internet for a solution, but cannot seem to find one which works with this code. What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid, but I'm new to C# and programming in general.

The error is as follows: Error  4   A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

Comment: Parentheses...e.Result.Text.ToUpper()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToUpper` should be a method `ToUpper()`, you are lacking parentheses

Comment: Thanks, but after adding the (), I get a some weird errors concerning the commands. I'll take another look quick.

Comment: Oh. I had some incorrect functions and such. I've fixed it now. Thanks!